# Confusion around no of CUDA Cores and the number of parallel threads

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, nvidia

I have NVIDIA Corporation TU117 [GeForce GTX 1650] as my GPU. The specs are as below.

No of SM's = 14
No of cuda cores per SM - 64
Total no of cuda cores - 64*14 = 896

I have read that blocks are executed sequentially and that one SM can execute one block at once
Each cuda core can execute 32 threads at once simultaneously(warps). So, each SM can execute 64 times 32 = 2048 threads simultaneously. But the max no of threads per block is 1024. So, when i assign one block to one SM (as told earlier, cannot assign multiple blocks to one SM), that means that SM can max run 1024 threads at once(limited by max block thread size

Doesn't that mean that SM only runs at half (2048/1024) of it's max capacity?
So, the max no of threads i can run simultaneously is 1024(max block thread size) times 14(no of SM's). Is that correct?
Also, is the data given here on NVIDIA Corporation TU117 [GeForce GTX 1650] correct?

Comment: There can be multiple blocks per SM.

Answer (score 2):

> I have read that blocks are executed sequentially and that one SM can execute one block at once

I'm not sure where you read that.  It's incorrect.  An SM can have multiple blocks resident and the warp schedulers in an SM on a cycle by cycle basis can choose any assigned warps to issue instructions from.

> Each cuda core can execute 32 threads at once simultaneously(warps).

No, not correct.  A cuda core as that term is used by NVIDIA marketing most closely corresponds to a single precision functional unit in an SM. On any given clock cycle, a cuda core can be issued a single FADD, FMUL, or FFMA instruction for a single thread in a warp.  To handle such an instruction warp-wide in a single cycle would require 32 cuda cores, just for that one warp, for that one instruction.

> So, each SM can execute 64 times 32 = 2048 threads simultaneously.

The previous statements are incorrect, and so this calculation is also.  That is not how you compute the number of simultaneous threads that can be handled by an SM.  A Turing SM can handle 1024 threads max as indicated [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications-technical-specifications-per-compute-capability) ("maximum number of resident threads per SM").  It's a hardware limit.

> Doesn't that mean that SM only runs at half (2048/1024) of it's max capacity?

The max capacity of the Turing SM is 1024 threads. There is no inconsistency.

> So, the max no of threads i can run simultaneously is 1024(max block thread size) times 14(no of SM's). Is that correct?

Yes, the maximum number of threads that can be simultaneously "in-flight" on any CUDA GPU is the maximum number of threads per SM times the number of SMs.  This doesn't mean that a kernel launch is numerically limited to that many threads.  Additional threads will "wait in the wings" until threads currently running on a SM complete and retire, making space for additional threads to be deposited.

> Also, is the data given here on NVIDIA Corporation TU117 [GeForce GTX 1650] correct?

You can get the number of SMs and the max number of threads per multiprocessor on any CUDA GPU by running the [deviceQuery sample code](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery).

Unit 3 of [this online training series](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/cuda-training-series/) may be of interest, as it covers GPU architecture and warp scheduling info.  In addition, there are numerous question here on the `cuda` SO tag that cover these topics. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147624/how-many-cuda-cores-is-used-to-process-a-cuda-warp/62160925#62160925) is one example, there are many others.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. leaving aside additional threads "waiting in the wings" and the memory checks done, max parallelism i can achieve is <<<14,1024>> right? That means that 1 SM can process 1024 threads at once right?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking this question.  In my answer I stated that " A Turing SM can handle 1024 threads max " and "The max capacity of the Turing SM is 1024 threads. "  Now you are asking "That means that 1 SM can process 1024 threads at once right?".  If I have not already answered that question, then I am not sure what question you are now asking.

Comment: If by "at once" you mean all 1024 threads are scheduled in a given clock cycle, then no, it does not process 1024 threads "at once".  As I said in my answer, the warp schedulers can choose from among those 1024 threads (32 warps) in any given clock cycle, for an instruction to schedule, warp-wide.

Comment: Basically, i need to perform point addition on secp256k1 curve over 500 billion times(play around with values each time).Using 8 CPU cores, i divided 500 billion into 8 batches, used multithreading.Total operation time is 6-7 days.Thats too long as i need to perform such operations 200+times. So, i wrote the code for point addition in C which is applicable in cuda kernel code.So, now the question is how many batches can i divide 500 billion into so that each batch runs as one thread? How many threads can i have running at the same time with each thread doing one batch?

Comment: No need to worry about that.  Spin up as many threads as you need.  This hyper-attention on the number of threads in flight is not a first-order optimization concern.  You would learn this with an orderly introduction to CUDA, such as [here](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/cuda-training-series/).

Comment: I will check that course out.. But now, let's say each thread performs 50 million calculations. So, i need 10000 threads to cover 500 billion calculations. Will those 10000 threads run concurrently? Cuz if few threads are in "waiting period" lets say, i do have to wait for the next batch of threads to finish. Instead of that, Im thinking of not having any "waiting" threads and then divide the workload(here its 50mil) acc to max no of threads i can run simultaneuosly.. Sorry for my basic knowledge in CUDA. Just Playing with the cards i hold.

Comment: I don't know what "waiting period" means.  If you have 500 billion calculations, and you want to do 50 million calculations per thread, then spin up 10,000 threads.  That is probably on the small side, but may be ok for your small-side GPU (14x1024 ~ 14,000 threads max in flight).  Or else you could do 500 billion / (14x1024) calculations per thread.  It's impossible to know if the 10000 threads will run concurrently without more info.  But it is theoretically possible for them to run concurrently, according to the definition I gave in my answer.  You could have up to 14x1024 threads running.

Comment: "without more info" what info is needed to arrive at a judgement? "waiting period" here in the sense means the time one thread has to wait before gpu resource frees up for it to be executed.. Info about GPU -  NVIDIA Corporation TU117 [GeForce GTX 1650]

Comment: The number of threads that a SM can support has a hardware limit of 1024 (for Turing).  But there are other factors (specifics of the code you are running) that could further reduce the number of threads that can actually be resident on a Turing SM.  This is in the general subject area of CUDA **occupancy** and there are many questions and also learning material and documentation available on it.  Providing a full tutorial on CUDA in the space of comments is not really sensible I don't think.  I'm unlikely to answer further questions here.

Comment: Thank you for providing some insight. I'll read up. Thank you for responding.